# Detecting a id's presence in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I am parsing LinkedIn usernames and a lot of them have an alphanumeric id appended to the end and I am trying to create a regex to detect them.

Example) `https://linkedin.com/in/john-smith-83a5268`

Example) `https://linkedin.com/in/jane-doe-27088994`

Some of the characteristics of the id that I noticed:

1. The id's are not always the same amount of characters
2. Sometimes users dont have the id in their name ex) `bob-smith` or `Rachel` (username doesn't always have a `-`)
3. alpha numeric

What Ive been trying to do and failing is:

So I want to match on a string that has at least one `-` in it and to the right of the `-` has both numbers and letters within the word

My regex: `(-{2})[a-zA-Z0-9]+`

Would anyone know how to do this?
--Thanks :)

Comment: `-{3}` matches exactly 3 consecutive `-`. Where does that appear in the URLs?

Comment: @Barmar I meant {2} for a typical string will have two `-` in them. I'm not honestly sure I'm new at regex

Comment: `27088994` doesn't have both numbers and letters, it only has numbers.

Comment: @Barmar Okay yea missed that. So I guess the new requirements are has at least numbers in it and maybe letters

Comment: Are you sure it can't be just letters? I suspect it's a hex number, and they can be just letters.

Comment: @Barmar From all of the test cases I have it doesn't seem like there is any instance where it is all letters.

Comment: Try using a capturing group and match at least a single digit `-([a-zA-Z\d]*\d[a-zA-Z\d]*)$`  See https://regex101.com/r/EKicuN/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regexp will match a string containing a mix of digits and optional letters, preceded by `-`, and at the end of the input string.

```
(?<=-)(?=.*?\d)[a-z\d]+$
```

`(?<=-)` is a positive lookbehind that matches `-`. `(?=.*?\d)` is a positive lookahead that matches at least one digit. And `[a-z\d]+$` matches a mix of digits and letters at the end of the string.

https://regex101.com/r/1qCqW2/1